# Password Rules histsize Ineffective for Some Users

Tags: password, aix

We're trying to deploy a tightened password policy on an AIX 5.3: Users are not allowed to reused last 24 passwords.
So, I change histsize from the previous value from 5 to 24 in /etc/security/user,

```
default:
  histsize = 24
```

I test successfully with my own non-superuser account, say named support001.
But it doesn't work for 2 user accounts, say named user017 and user117.

What I have tried to troubleshoot:

1. There is no stanza for these 2 accounts in /etc/security/user
2. run user checks, and add back 2 empty stanzas for these 2 accounts in /etc/security/user by vi

   usrck -n user017 user117
3. run pwdck, no error is found.

   pwdck -n user017 user117
4. check if there are double line spacing in any stanza in
   /etc/security/user
   /etc/security/passwd
   /etc/security/lastlog and 
   /etc/security/group

e.g., I experienced that will cause error when reading the parms

```
user017:
  someparm = 1


user117:
  someparm = 1

user217:
```

Finally, I fallback the setting, and find that even the original value histsize
= 5 is not working. Basically, users can reuse the last password just changed. Perhaps no one discovered it before.

What else should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as root:

```
pwdadm -c username
password username
```

Login to user, check if it change password applies.

If yes, set 1st password, afterwards change it (this time as *username*) and try to set the same password.

If it does not work, check `/etc/security/user`, search for *username* and add `histsize=2` (afterwards repeat all the steps).

You can also check it with `lsuser -a histsize username`

Also, make sure that the user has the following set:

```
lsuser -a auth1 username
```

Must return `auth1=SYSTEM`

```
lsuser -a registry username
```

Must return `registry=files`

If it does not work paste here the output of `lsuser -f username`